# upper bound of ramsey number $r(p_1+1,\ldots,p_n+1)$

Tags: graph-theory

The problem is proving $r(p_1+1,\ldots,p_n+1)\leq \frac{(p_1+\ldots+p_n)!}{p_1!\ldots p_n!}$

I think it can be proved in a similar way of $r(p+1,q+1)\leq \binom{p+q}{p}$ which uses $r(p+1,q+1)\leq r(p+1,q)+r(p,q+1)$

I found an useful inequlation $(_1,\ldots,_)≤2−+\sum_{=1}^(_1,…,_{−1},_−1,_{+1},…,_)$ but there I cannot found the proof of it.
[Upper bound for ramsey number $r(a_1,\ldots, a_m)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304682/upper-bound-for-ramsey-number-ra-1-ldots-a-m)